# How to use protected route in react with passport.js

Tags: reactjs, express, react-router, passport.js

How to use protected route in react after login with passport.js

So, what I found is after successful login via passport.js, when I send request to server from front-end there is user property in request (i.e. req.user).

What I tried is putting axios.get to "/authenticate" url in app component's componentDidMount method for checking if user did login and I realized that componentDidMount is called only once before user do anything for logging in.
I also tried to put axios get in componentDidUpdate and it also was not working properly.

Before using password I had auth.js in client side and just simply checked ID and password, if it's correct ID and password, auth.isAuthenticated become true and protected route's component was accessible. It worked except that when I refresh the page, it somehow doesn't remember previous auth.isAuthenticated and it's always false as its initial value and go to "/". 
So I moved to passport and having this problem...

Could anybody tell me how to do it?

'''javascript
//In server.js

```
app.get('/authenticate', function(req, res)  {
        if (req.user)
            res.send(true);
        else
            return null;
    });
```

'''
'''javascript
//in app.jsx

```
     constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = { isAuthenticated: false };
        }


    componentDidMount() {
            axios.get('/authenticate').then((res) => {
                if (res)
                    this.setState({ isAuthenticated: true });
            })
            console.log("componentDidMount in errand-app")
            console.log(this.state.isAuthenticated);
        }

    render() {
            let { isAuthenticated } = this.state;
            return <div>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={LoginPage} />
                    <ProtectedRoute isAuthenticated= 
   {this.state.isAuthenticated} exact path="/main" component={Main} />
```

'''

'''javascript
//In protectedRoute

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, isAuthenticated, ...rest 
}) => {
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={props => {
                if (isAuthenticated) {
                    return <Component {...props} />;
                }
                else {
                    return (
                        <Redirect
                            to={{pathname: "/",
                                state: { from: props.location
                                 }
                            }}
                        />
                    );
                }
            }
            }
        />
    )
}
```

'''

I want to my protectedRoute has props like isAuthenticated and only when it's true, show the component otherwise redirect to "/" which is login page.

Comment: I have created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/EduVencovsky/f8f6c275f42f7352571c92a59309e31d) that handles `PriveteRoutes` and a have a context for Authentication. You can check it out if you want

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an answer long overdue but maybe it will help anyone else struggling with this. There is quite a few steps to this solution but I hope it will be helpful.

First of all, for communication between Express and React, I implemented JSON Web Token. For purposes of this question, I'll leave out *passport-config.js* out, because it doesn't require anything special.

In express, **server/server.js**

```js
if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {require('dotenv').config();}
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const initializePassport = require('./passport-config');
const passport = require('passport');
const session = require('express-session');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const app = express();
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
//const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
//app.use(cookieParser({secret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});


// JWT

const verifyJWT = (req, res, next) =>{ // This function is a JWT middleware
    const token = req.headers['x-access-token'];
    if (!token){
        res.send("Token not provided!");

    }else {
        jwt.verify(token, "jwtSecret", {},(err, decoded)=>{
            if (err){
                console.log(err);
                res.json({auth: false, message: "Token verification failed"});
            }else{
                req.userId = decoded.id;
                next();
            }
        });
    }
}


// Cors
const whitelist = process.env.WHITELISTED_DOMAINS
    ? process.env.WHITELISTED_DOMAINS.split(",")
    : []

const corsOptions = {
    origin: function (origin, callback) {
        if (!origin || whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
            callback(null, true)
        } else {
            callback(new Error("Not allowed by CORS"))
        }
    },
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"],
    credentials: true,
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions))

// knex & bookshelf
const knex = require('knex')({
    client: "mysql",
    connection: {
        host: "localhost",
        user: "dbuser",
        password: "dbpassword",
        database: "cookmesomethingdb"
    }
});
const bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);

async function createBookshelfOf(tbl){
    return bookshelf.Model.extend({
        tableName: tbl,
        idAttribute: "id"
    });
}

async function insertInto(table, obj){ // Helper function for INSERT
    await knex(table).insert(obj)
        .then(()=>console.log("INSERTED: " + obj + ", INTO table: " + table))
        .catch((err)=>{console.log(err); throw err;})
}

// Passport
initializePassport(
    passport,
    async username=>{
        try{
            let bookshelfUser = await createBookshelfOf("Users");
            return await new bookshelfUser().where("username", username).fetch().then((data)=>{
                return data.attributes;
            });
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            return null;
        }},
    async id=>{
        try{
            let bookshelfUser = await createBookshelfOf("Users");
            return await new bookshelfUser().where("idUsers", id).fetch().then((data)=>{
                return data.attributes;
            });
        }
        catch (e) {
            return null;
        }});

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", req.header('origin'));
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});

/* Session*/
app.use(session({
    secret : process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized : false
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(methodOverride('__method'));

// Authentication

app.post('/login', (req, res, next)=>{
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect : '/',
        failureRedirect  : '/login'
    }, (err, user, info)=>{
        if(err){res.status(500).send(err); return;}
        if(!user){
            res.json({auth: false, message: "Could not fetch user"});
            return;
        }
        req.logIn(user, (err)=>{
            if(err){return next(err)}
        
            const id = user.idUsers;
            const token = jwt.sign({id}, "jwtSecret", {
                expiresIn: 300
            });
            let usrObj = {
                id: user.idUsers,
                username: user.username,
                name: user.name,
                surname: user.surname
            }
            res.status(200).json({auth: true, token: token, result: usrObj});
        });
    })(req, res, next);
});

app.get('/isAuth', verifyJWT, (req,res)=>{ // testing purposes
    res.send("Authentication successful")
})


app.post("/register", async(req, res) => {
    try{
        let Users = await createBookshelfOf("Users");
        let users = await new Users().fetchAll()
        for (let user of users.toJSON()){
            if (user.username === req.body.username){
                res.status(500).send("Username exists")
                return
            }
        }
        const hashedPassword = bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10);
        let obj = [{
            username: req.body.username,
            name: req.body.name,
            surname: req.body.surname,
            password: hashedPassword
        }];

        insertInto("Users", obj);
        res.status(200).send("Successfully inserted data")

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message)
        res.status(500).send(e.message);

    }
});



// Server config

const PORT = 4000; // backend routing port
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

So this part should be straight forward. First you create verifitcation of JWT and inside login function we first sign the token and then send data (auth: loginStatus, token:jwt, result: userObject)

The react part: **client/components/auth.js**

```js
import {useState, createContext, useContext} from "react";
import React from 'react'
const AuthContext = createContext(null);

export const AuthProvider = ({children})=>{
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

    const login = (user) =>{
        setUser(user);
    }
    const logout = () =>{
        setUser(null);
    }

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, login, logout}}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}

export const useAuth = () =>{
    return useContext(AuthContext)
}
```

useAuth will allow us to check if user is logged in later on

Then, you need to retrieve JWT from Express for which I used Axios.

**client/components/Login.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import '../css/components.css';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import {useState} from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import {useAuth} from './auth'
const styles = {
    h2Login: {
        textAlign: "center",
        fontSize: "25px"
    },
    divLogin: {
        textAlign:"center",
        paddingTop: "15px"
    },
    loginA: {
        fontSize: "15px"
    },
    margins: {
        marginTop: "5px"
    }
}


function Login(){

    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [loginUsername, setLoginUsername] = useState("")
    const [loginPassword, setLoginPassword] = useState("")
    const [loginStatus, setLoginStatus] = useState(false);
    
    const auth = useAuth();
    const login = () => {
        Axios({
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                username: loginUsername,
                password: loginPassword,
            },
            withCredentials: true,
            url: "http://localhost:4000/login",
        }).then((res) => {
                if(res.data.auth === true){
                    setLoginStatus(true)
                    localStorage.setItem('jwt', res.data.token) // Save JWT in local storage
                    auth.login(res.data.result); // Log in with user sent from Express
                    navigate('/', {replace: true});
                }else {
                    setLoginStatus(false);
                }

            }

        ).catch((err)=>{console.log(err)});
    };


    const handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
    };
    const reroute = (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        navigate('/register');
    }

    return(
        <section className="justify-content-center" >
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row justify-content-center">
                    <div className="col-lg-8">
                        <div>
                            <div className="form-input login-form">
                                <h2 style={styles.h2Login}>Login Form</h2>
                                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="login-form">
                                    <div className="form-group">
                                        <input className="form-control form-control-md input-thingy" type="text" placeholder="username"
                                               onChange={(e) => setLoginUsername(e.target.value)}
                                        />

                                    </div>
                                    <div className="form-group ">
                                        <input className="form-control input-thingy" type="password" placeholder="password" id="password"
                                           onChange={(e) => setLoginPassword(e.target.value)}
                                        />

                                    </div>

                                        <button style={styles.margins} type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={login}>Login</button>
                                    { loginStatus &&(<button
                                    onClick={userAuthenticated}>Check if log in was successful</button>)}
                                    <div style={styles.divLogin}>
                                        <a style={styles.loginA} className="" onClick={reroute}
                                            >Don't
                                            have an account?</a>

                                    </div>

                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </section>
    )
}



export default Login;
```

next, we need to make a function that will check authorization

**client/components/RequireAuth.js**

```js
import  { useAuth } from "./auth";
import React from "react";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

export const RequireAuth = ({children}) => {
    const auth = useAuth();
    if (!auth.user){
        return <Navigate to='/login'/>
    }
    return children;
}
```

This part just checks if user is passed while logging in.  If authentication fails, we are redirected back to login page. At this point, there are two options for protecting the route. First option is using our *RequireAuth wrapper* and inside route, we just wrap the "protected" component. What this will do, it will redirect us to either the desired page if authentication was successful or to login page

**client/App.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import Nav from "./components/Nav.js";
import { AuthProvider } from "./components/auth";
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./components/Login.js"
import Register from "./components/Register"

import Profile from "./components/Profile";
import {RequireAuth} from "./components/RequireAuth";

function App() {
    return (
        <AuthProvider>
            <Router>
            <div className="App">
                <header>
                    <Nav/>
                    <Routes>
                        <Route path='/login' element={<Login/>} />
                        <Route path='/register' element={<Register/>}/>
                        <Route path='/profile' element={<RequireAuth><Profile/></RequireAuth>}/>
                    </Routes>
                </header>
            </div>
            </Router>
        </AuthProvider>
    );
}
export default App
```

...or you could hide the routes entirely in the NavBar file (assumming you have one) by passing a simple if statement:

**client/components/Nav.js**

```js
import React from 'react'; //ES6
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import '../css/components.css'
import {useAuth} from "./auth";

function Nav(){
    const auth = useAuth()
    return (
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-transparent">
                <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                    <ul className="navbar-nav">
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            {
                                !auth.user && (
                                    <Link to='/login' className="nav-link">Login</Link>
                                )
                            }


                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            {
                                !auth.user && (
                                    <Link to='/register' className="nav-link">Register</Link>
                                )
                            }
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            {
                                auth.user && (
                                    <Link to='/profile' className="nav-link">Profile</Link>
                                )
                            }

                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
        </nav>
    );
}

export default Nav;
```

So basically what you're doing in the *nav.js* file is saying, if user is authenticated, I want to display the  component.

Hope anyone finds this useful